# Why am I unable to sign back into Pokemon Go

Tags: pokemon-go

I accidentally signed out of my account and when I type in my details for Google it will take me to a page where there are Pokemon staring at me and it says, our servers are humbled etc. Why am I unable to sign back into the application?

Comment: @KutuluMike that's not the same question. This one mentions about servers but the one you linked doesn't. The other link does mention servers.

Comment: it's still the same question. these are all symptoms of the same thing: the servers are overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

It just sounds like the servers are busy right now due to a lot of people playing during this time. The best way is to just wait a bit until the servers aren't as overloaded with people.